Как удалить сообщение от бота aiogram
не удалось найти способ удаления сообщения от бота
@dp.message(F.text)
async def dice(message: Message):
 dice_value = (await message.answer_dice(DiceEmoji.DICE)).dice.value # это нужно удалить
 print(dice_value)


Вообще сообщение удаляется так:
@dp.message(F.text)
async def dice(message: Message):
    dice_value = await message.answer_dice(DiceEmoji.DICE)
    print(dice_value.dice.value) # Если хотите видеть вывод в консоли
    await asyncio.sleep(5) # Ждем 5 секунд
    await dice_value.delete() # Удаляем сообщение

но, вы получите ошибку:
aiogram.exceptions.TelegramBadRequest: Telegram server says - Bad Request: message can't be deleted for everyone

потому что согласно Документации:
A dice message in a private chat can only be deleted if it was sent more than 24 hours ago.

т.е. сообщение с подбрасыванием кубика в приватном чате можно удалить лишь в том случае, если с момента отправки прошло более 24 часов
